# c++ multiple inheritence constructor calling

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the following lines class A is the base class, inherited by classes B and C.
Class D inherits from both B and C. Furthermore, the constructor in D calls constructors of B, C and A.
Because when B and C inherit A as virtual, they are not eligible to call constructor of A directly (as the call to same must be made through 3rd generation).

My question is, if I want to make an object of class B, then as A is inherited virtually, is there anyway to call constructor of A (to pass v1 and v2, the variables to be used for initialization)?

```
class A {
   int a1,a2;
   A() {
   }

   A(int v1,v2) {
      a1 = v1;
      a2 = v2;
   }
};

class B:virtual public A {
   int b1,b2;
   B() {
   }

   B(int v1,v2) {
      b1 = v1;
      b2 = v2;
   }
};

class C:virtual public A {
   int c1,c2;
   C() {
   }

   C(int v1,v2) {
      c1 = v1;
      c2 = v2;
   }
};

class D:public B,public C {
   int d1,d2;
   D() {
   }

   D(int v1,v2):B(v1,v2),C(v1,v2),A(v1,v2)
   {
      d1 = v1;
      d2 = v2;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to also give `B` an initializer for `A`. All that virtual inheritance means is that **if** you have an even-more-derived object, then the virtual base is constructed by the most-derived object. But if you're only constructing an instance of `B`, then that instance *is* the most derived object. So just write it like this:

```
 class B : public virtual A
 {
 public:
     B() : A(1, 2) {  }
     // ...
 };
```

It's only when you *derive from `B`* that the base initializer is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to make classes B and C inherit normally (without keyword 'virtual') from A, but make class D to inhert virtually from B and C. That will allow you to create object of class B (or C) by passing values for class A constructor>